# How do I make a triangle space with text written for the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, geometry, drawtext

I want to draw a triangle and elide text in the shape.  I can restrict the triangle to an equilateral triangle and a fixed orientation ('upside down' or 'upside up').  Then I want to insert arbitrary text in the triangle such that the eliding is on word boundaries and not clipped.

Any simple algorithms?  What methods are available in Objective-C?

I am thinking of calculating lines of rectangles of 'font height' and width bounded by the top-side as it intersects the triangle's sides.  Then draw-text of the remaining text into each rectangle until done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the 3.2 SDK...

Comment: I trust your answers Dave!  Thanks for listening.